# Unable to retrieve cloudWatch GetMetricData in Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

I need to get MetricData in Node.js application for my AWS Lambda
[image]

Error received:

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/dev-rohit-ap-southeast-1-lambdaRole/dev-rohit-uploader is not authorized to perform: cloudwatch:GetMetricData\n    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)\n    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

Serverless.yaml

```
- Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "lambda:GetMetricData"
      Resource: arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-uploader
```

Getting Metric Data function

```js
exports.getMetrics = async () => {
  const params = {
    EndTime: '2021-09-07T03:04:00Z',
    MetricDataQueries: [
      {
        Id: 'concurrencycount',
        Label: 'Average concurrency',
        MetricStat: {
          Metric: {
            Dimensions: [
              {
                Name: 'upload',
                Value: process.env.S3_UPLOAD_BUCKET
              },
            ],
            MetricName: 'Invocations',
            Namespace: 'AWS/Lambda'
          },
          Period: '300',
          Stat: 'Average',
          Unit: 'Count'
        },
        ReturnData: false
      },
    ],
    StartTime: '2021-09-07T03:01:00Z',
    //ScanBy: TimestampDescending
  };

  try {
    return await client().getMetricData(params).promise()
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error, 'Error getting metrics from Lambda Cloudwatch')
    throw error
  }
}
```

What I tried :

1. Updated Action
   ***in serverless.yaml***

   Action:

   - "cloudwatch:GetMetricData"
2. Updated ARN to

   Resource: arn:aws:lambda:${self:custom.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-uploader
3. Updated

   Resource: arn:aws:logs:${self:custom.region}:${self:custom.accountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${self:service}-${opt:stage}-uploader:*

didn't work.

Resources:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#getMetricData-property

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try to get the data through epoch time in EndTime and EndTime of params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Resource to `*` and use condition keys to limit the access scope:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/iam-cw-condition-keys-namespace.html

So your policy statement might look something like:

```yaml
- Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "cloudwatch:GetMetricData"
      Resource: "*"
      Condition:
         StringEquals:
             "cloudwatch:namespace": "AWS/Lambda"
```

Comment: No, Got the same error
Updated 
Action:
        - "cloudwatch:GetMetricData"
Also tried with cloudwatch:namespace without double quotes.

Comment: What if you try it without any condition? Just use the correct action (updated my answer) and try `*` for resource

Comment: worked without condition but doesn't get any metrics too; "MetricDataResults": [], is retrieved in cloudWatch.

Comment: Then you need to confirm that this metric you're looking for actually exists in the specified namespace.

Comment: sorry, Did not catch you there.
I am looking for <<MetricName: 'Invocations',
            Namespace: 'AWS/Lambda'>> which is in AWS/Lambda.
thats in the code

Comment: I meant that you need to confirm that this metric actually exists in the environment.